# Echo price of product in virtuemart cart

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I use joomla 2.5 and virtuemart 2. I tried to echo a script that is built from php.
So inside cart file inside foreach function that goes through each product I need to save to a variable product id, quantity and sales price.

I can show product id and quantity like this:

```
$wantedproductid = $product->virtuemart_product_id;
$wantedproductquantity = $product->quantity;
```

but I have a problem with price. I echoed `$this` and I get this:

```
VirtueMartCart Object
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [812] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [virtuemart_manufacturer_id] => 11
                    [slug] => hill-s-puppy-healthy-development-large-breed-koutavia-anaptyksi-kotopoulo-11kg
                    [published] => 1

...
...
    [pricesUnformatted] => Array
        (
            [basePrice] => 70.6
            [basePriceWithTax] => 0
            [discountedPriceWithoutTax] => 60.31
            [salesPrice] => 60.31
            [taxAmount] => 0
            [salesPriceWithDiscount] => 60.31
            [discountAmount] => 57.4
            [priceWithoutTax] => 70.6
            [subTotalProducts] => 0
            [2Diff] => -9.585
            [812] => Array
                (
                    [costPrice] => 63.90000
                    [basePrice] => 63.9
                    [basePriceVariant] => 63.9
                    [basePriceWithTax] => 0
                    [discountedPriceWithoutTax] => 54.32
                    [priceBeforeTax] => 63.9
                    [salesPrice] => 54.32
                    [taxAmount] => 0
                    [salesPriceWithDiscount] => 54.32
                    [salesPriceTemp] => 54.32
                    [unitPrice] => 0
                    [discountAmount] => 14.99
                    [priceWithoutTax] => 63.9
                    [variantModification] => 0
                   ...
...
```

What I need is for example this value: `[salesPrice] => 54.32`

How can I save `[salesPrice]` in a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
echo $this->pricesUnformatted['salesPrice']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Correct answer: $product->product_price

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong, that did't work not the answer nor the comment below the answer.
This works:

```
echo $this->cart->pricesUnformatted[$wantedproductid]['salesPrice'];
```

but it shows sales price only of the last product of the cart not for each product. The foreach condition works fine

Comment: You are right. The first response does not work, yours work but as you told only for last product. Any ideas?